# Send multiple notifications androidle

Tags: android

I am trying to recieve multiple notifications on my mobile.But each time i send the notification.The previous notification gets overwritten by the new one.I watched the other questions where they said to have multiple `Id's` for notifications I am doing that also but I don't know where I am going wrong.

Here's how I create my notification.(It is being created in a service).

```
private void GenerateNotification(String data)
{
    String ns=Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
    manager=(NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);

    int icon=R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, data, when);
    notification.flags |=Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence contentTitle = "The Best Essay";
    CharSequence contentText = data;
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
    manager.notify(HELLO_ID, notification);
    HELLO_ID++;
}
```

Where HelloID increments to recieve multiple notifications with unique id's.Please tell me where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue is that the intent you're using is the same each time. If you try to notify the user using an Intent that is the same as one used in a notification that is already being displayed, android considers them duplicates. This is because each notification when clicked will end up doing the exact same thing (so android is like "why do I need to display two of these?").

The thing to do is say "hey, am I already displaying a notification? If so, I'm going to create a new notification that will override the current one, but convey the fact that there are actually two things that I'm notifying about". Consider the text messaging application. When you get a second unread text message, it overrides the first notification about the original text message and replaces it with a notification tell you that you have two new text messages. Make sense?

Comment: great explanation thnx.But i want to show seperate notifications because the data that I will be recieveing in the notification will help me to seperate the data shown in the next activity after the notification gets clicked.

Comment: So in your intent store all the data that you'll need. Then let your activity sort it out. Going back to the text message example, if there are multiple text messages you need to show, the notification is going to take you to a list of all your unread text messages instead of a specific text message, and then let you choose which text message you want to view first.

Comment: ah thnx the best explanation.Do you've a blog or something I would love to follow it :)

Comment: hmmmmm, not at the moment, though I have an old one that I guess I could start back up again. Maybe I'll make this my first post. I'll let you know if/when I do.

Comment: oh thats great.Do not forget to tell me :)